# Is there a way to track when the users get the call in twilio js

Tags: javascript, twilio

i've tried with the `conn.status()` but as soon as the call starts "ringing" the status change to "open"
i've tried with the `conn.accept(function(conn){ // do something })` but doesn't appear to work.

I want to put a timer for the call duration, but now i'm only available to start it when the call starts rining.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The JS SDK doesn't show you the call progress events I'm afraid.

However, you can subscribe to call progress events via webhooks. In your TwiML that sets up the call, you can supply a URL as the [`statusCallback` attribute on the `<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback) element. You will then get webhook callbacks to that URL when the call moves through the various events, including [initiated, ringing, answered and completed](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event).

If you set up a real time connection to your front end using server sent events or a websocket, you can then display your timer when the correct webhook arrives.

Let me know if that helps at all.